# Mounting by block address

Tags: linux, mount

Is it possible to do a partial mount in Linux? Lets say that you have 1 partition or one device file that contains 50 blocks. You want to write one file system to blocks 0-24, and something else in 25-49. Is there away to mount based on the block locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the options `offset` and `sizelimit` to mount. These get passed to `losetup` and allow you to specify the start and length of the part of the device that you want to use. Both are specified in bytes.

As pointed out by [Wumpus Q. Wumbley](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/41515/wumpus-q-wumbley) in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83550/mounting-by-block-address/83552?noredirect=1#comment124034_83552), you can pass the same parameters to losetup yourself and then create a file system on the corresponding loop device.

It all should work independently of which file system you are using. See `man 8 losetup` and `man 8 mount` (the latter under `THE LOOP DEVICE`).

Comment: Creating the filesystem can be done by running the losetup first, with the same parameters you will later use for mounting, then mk*fs on the loop device.

Comment: That poses some interesting use cases, you could create a delieverable OS via a single image file. Or maybe this is how VHDs already work... oh well

Comment: @monksy I seriously doubt that's how virtual hard disks are implemented. More likely the VM host software simply maps any disk accesses to file reads and writes at the given offsets (possibly adjusting for splitting the virtual disk into multiple files), and doesn't care what you are doing inside the VM as long as you are "physically" within the boundaries of the "disk".